# Android - Playing the sound of dialer button

Tags: android, audio, keyboard-events

I'm writing my custom dialer keyboard. Does anyone know how to play sound of tap to system dialer pad?(* # 0..9)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [ToneGenerator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator.html) class. It contains the correct tones and a way to play them. This is how the default Dialer app plays the tones.

Comment: Yes, that's excactly what I wanted. Thank you)